# Installing lxml module in python

Tags: python, lxml, python-import

while running a python script, I got this error

```
  from lxml import etree
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

now I tried to install lxml

```
sudo easy_install lmxl
```

but it gives me the following error

```
Building lxml version 2.3.beta1.
NOTE: Trying to build without Cython, pre-generated 'src/lxml/lxml.etree.c' needs to be available.
ERROR: /bin/sh: xslt-config: not found

** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **
```

Using build configuration of libxslt

```
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 112):

Just do:

```
sudo apt-get install python-lxml
```

For Python 2 (e.g., required by Inkscape):

```
sudo apt-get install python2-lxml
```

If you are planning to install from source, then [albertov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598229/installing-lxml-module-in-python/4598317#4598317) will help. But unless there is a reason, don't, just install it from the repository.

Comment: If you're using a virtual environment this is not the right answer.

Comment: for venv, just upgrade the lxml pip install --upgrade lxml

Answer (score 97):

I solved it upgrading the lxml version with:

```
pip install --upgrade lxml
```

Comment: must do this in venv

Answer (score 50):

You need to install Python's header files (python-dev package in debian/ubuntu) to compile lxml. As well as libxml2, libxslt, libxml2-dev, and libxslt-dev:

```
apt-get install python-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

Comment: and libxml2-dev and libxslt-dev.

Comment: **libxslt** does not seem to be required (it was not for me, at least).
Therefore, `apt-get install python-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev` should be enough

Comment: I had to do this to install WeasyPrint, their `apt-get` instructions for Debian 7 alone didn't work.

Comment: **libxslt** was essential for me, lxml setup wouldn't go through without it.

Answer (score 41):

If you're running python3, you'll have to do:

`pip3 install lxml`

Comment: This is what worked for me! I was using the python3 and installing libraries for a previous version of python via `pip`. For `python3`, we should use `pip3`.

Answer (score 7):

For python 3 this worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install python3-lxml
```

Answer (score 6):

For RHEL/CentOS, run "python --version" command to find out Python version. E.g. below:

```
$ python --version 
  Python 2.7.12
```

Now run "sudo yum search lxml" to find out python*-lxml package.

```
$ sudo yum search lxml
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
1014 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
============================================================================================================= N/S matched: lxml =============================================================================================================
python26-lxml-docs.noarch : Documentation for python-lxml
python27-lxml-docs.noarch : Documentation for python-lxml
python26-lxml.x86_64 : ElementTree-like Python bindings for libxml2 and libxslt
python27-lxml.x86_64 : ElementTree-like Python bindings for libxml2 and libxslt
```

Now you can choose package as per your Python version and run command like below:

```
$ sudo yum install python27-lxml.x86_64
```

Comment: I am on Windows. Any solutions?

Comment: use "python2.7.exe -m pip install --upgrade lxml"

Answer (score 0):

If you are encountering this issue on an Alpine based image try this :

```
apk add --update --no-cache g++ gcc libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev make
```

// pip install -r requirements.txt