# Pip is already installed: but I am getting no module named lxml

Tags: python, lxml, python-import

I have installed lxml with pip. But when I run a script that uses lxml, I get "no module named lxml." Why might this be? How do I fix it?

```
(venv)prompt$ sudo pip install lxml
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
(venv)prompt$ python scripts/pyftp.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/pyftp.py", line 5, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

Comment: can you show the output of `which python` ?

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598229/installing-lxml-module-in-python

Comment: I think you are working in a virtualenv, so you have to install it without sudo.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are in a virtualenv. You probably do not want to be root when installing new packages.