# Can't install lxml in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml, linux-mint

Im trying to install lxml within a virtualenv with `sudo pip install lxml` and also `sudo pip install --upgrade lxml` but getting the following in both cases:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,
relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes    
-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat 
-Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -lxslt 
-lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/etree.so

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-nmFOYf-record/install-record.txt 
--single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in 
/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I have tried all the posted solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598229/installing-lxml-module-in-python), which implies that I have `libxml2-dev`, `libxslt-dev` and `python-dev` installed and I also installed `build-essential` 
I'm currently running Linux Mint 17 Debian Based which uses `apt-get` as package manager.
`python-lxml` was already preinstalled.

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` within a virtualenv? Did you create the virtualenv as root? If so, why? Or are you trying to install it to the system site-packages even though you're inside a virtualenv? If so, why not do it from outside the virtualenv?

Comment: @abarnert Well, the first time I did it without the sudo, then I tried installing lxml globally, but didn't work.

Comment: Just randomly mixing virtualenv and global installs with and without sudo is just going to lead to a broken virtualenv with screwed up permissions. Don't do that.

Comment: FYI you don't need to edit your title to say "solved". Just marking an accepted answer (which you've done) is sufficient.

Comment: Also, in the future, for installation-related problems, please put the information about your platform in your question, ideally as a tag. If you'd had the Linux Mint tag in the first place, I could have just told you to `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` instead of trying to explain in the abstract that you need to use your platform's installer to install your platform's zlib development package.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for the advice, I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lxml` depends on various C libraries, and you have to have those C libraries installed—including their development files (headers, `.so` or `.a` libraries, etc.)—to build `lxml`. The [installation](http://lxml.de/installation.html) docs explain what prerequisites you need to build on your particular platform.

---

This error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
```

… means that the prerequisite you're missing is `libz`, aka `zlib`.

Since you're not on Windows, it's incredibly unlikely that you actually don't have `zlib` at all… but pretty plausible that you don't have the development files for `zlib`. On some platforms, most notably many linux distros, packages are typically split into separate pieces. For example, the parts of `zlib` needed at runtime may be in a package named `zlib`, while the parts needed for building other programs that need `zlib` in a package named `zlib-dev` or `zlib-devel`. The exact details depend on your exact platform.

That being said, if you don't have the `zlib` development files, you probably don't have the `libxml2` or `libxslt` development files either, because I don't know of any platform where installing those wouldn't have pulled in the `zlib` files as well.

At any rate, since you haven't told us what platform you're one (and distro, if linux), I don't know what package manager to use, what the packages are named, etc., but do whatever's appropriate for your platform.

---

Also:

> I already have `python-lxml` installed

You really shouldn't install the same package both with your distro's package manager and with `pip`; that's a great way to confuse yourself.

But at any rate, most likely you installed `python-lxml` from a binary package, not from source, which means you didn't need the build requirements. Now you're trying to build it from source, which means you do.

Comment: Thanks for your early answer, the reason why I tried installing both with pip and package manager (which is `apt-get`) is because the first one (pip) didn't work for me, so I tried installing `python-lxml` but it was __preinstalled__. Also I installed `libxml2` and `libxslt` before I tried to install `lxml`.

Comment: @helado: But did you install `libxml2-dev` and `libxslt-dev`, as both the installation docs and this answer explain?

Comment: If you mean by `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev` as the docs says, then yes, I did it like that.

Comment: First time I've encountered this error on Debian... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

On an ubuntu based linux distro you can use:

`sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

Comment: I faced the same problem. This command solved the problem. Thanks to @helado and kguest.