# Can't install lxml on pip

Tags: lxml

I can't install lxml on pip or pip3

I tried run the code on python3.11

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_html("https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hans/%E6%81%92%E7%94%9F%E6%8C%87%E6%95%B8")
```

It occurred a Import Error.
"ImportError: lxml not found, please install it"

So I tried to install the lxml. "pip install lxml"

However, it cannot be install.
** note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.**

And then, I had download the lxml-4.9.9-pp38-....whl
and entered "pip install c:/......." and it said whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Could someone do me a favor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing lxml module in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598229/installing-lxml-module-in-python)

Comment: Thank you. I have found the reason. lxml does not support for python 3.11, so I setup version 3.9.