# How to install dragnet package in python on Window10

Tags: python

I'm installing the dragnet package, but I faced to the the following error.

## pip install dragnet

Collecting dragnet
Using cached dragnet-2.0.4.tar.gz (7.3 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [17 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 353, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return hook(config_settings)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yxnzw1bn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yxnzw1bn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
self.run_setup()
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yxnzw1bn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yxnzw1bn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "", line 25, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

## note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

Comment: It's not the exact same error but try: [How do I install lxml?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4598340/17398665)

Comment: I've installed the lxml package.

Comment: But I have the error...

Comment: Should've written that into the question ^^, and are you sure that you have installed it for the right python version?

Comment: Error is the same

Comment: Update Python 3.12.0rc3